# Printing every unlock pattern in a 2d phone keypad in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function that prints all possible patterns like in the examples below. In every case, we must start in the top left of a 3x3 array. It's similar to the patterns to unlock mobile phones, except the line can't go diagonally and must pass through every box.

```
1--->2--->3           1--->2--->3
          |                     |
          v                     v
8<---7    4     or    6<---5<---4
|    ^    |           |
v    |    v           v
9    6<---5           7--->8--->9
```

I started by writing a code where `[0][0]` was assigned 1 then randomise the rest of the digits in the 2d array until `1[0]` or 0 was equal to 2, and so forth. But I feel like this is making the problem even more difficult to solve.

Then tried to use recursion to call the `makePattern` function again and again until the array is changed; however, it changes all values in the array to 2 because of these lines of code:

```
int value = 2;    
array[x][y] = value;
```

However, I don't how to loop this value so that it increases as the function is called again.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 3
#define COLUMN 3

int makePattern(int array[ROW][COLUMN], int x, int y);

int main(void) {
    int x, y;
    int count = 2;
    int i, j;

    int array[ROW][COLUMN] = {
        {'1', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '0', '0'},
    };

    makePattern(array, 0, 0);

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
            printf("%d", array[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int makePattern(int array[ROW][COLUMN], int x, int y) {
    int value = 2;
    array[x][y] = value;

    for (value = 2; value < 9; value++) {
        if (x + 1 < ROW && array[x+1][y] == '0') {
            makePattern(array, x + 1, y);
        }

        if (x - 1 >= 0 && array[x - 1][y] == '0') {
            makePattern(array, x - 1, y);
        }

        if (y + 1 < COLUMN && array[x][y + 1] == '0') {
            makePattern(array, x, y + 1);
        }

        if (y - 1 >= 0 && array[x][y - 1] == '0') {
            makePattern(array, x, y - 1);
        }

        value++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this problem is similar to this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-ways-to-make-mobile-lock-pattern/

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track here in that you're using a 3x3 matrix to keep track of state (visited nodes and to store the path taken), x/y coordinates to represent the current location and spawning four recurse calls to handle the possible move directions (with bounds checks).

However, I'm not sure the loop running to 9 is going to work--this will spawn 36 recursive calls per frame. This might be workable in some implementations, but I think the easiest approach is to treat each frame as exploring one possible direction given an x/y coordinate pair, then backtracking (undoing the move) after all directions have been explored recursively from that square. Whenever we hit the last step, we know we've explored all of the squares and it's time to print the current solution path.

Here's code which achieves this and basically hardcodes the dimensions. An exercise would be to generalize the code to matrices of any size and return the path to separate printing from the traversal logic. I also opted to move state out of the `main` function.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_unlock_patterns_r(int pad[3][3], int x, int y, int step) {
    static int const directions[][2] = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};
    pad[y][x] = 1 + step;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int xp = x + directions[i][0];
        int yp = y + directions[i][1];

        if (xp >= 0 && xp < 3 && yp >= 0 && yp < 3 && !pad[yp][xp]) {
            print_unlock_patterns_r(pad, xp, yp, step + 1);
        }
    }

    if (step == 8) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, puts("")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; printf("%d", pad[i][j++]));
        }

        puts("");
    }    

    pad[y][x] = 0;
}

void print_unlock_patterns() {
    int pad[3][3];
    memset(pad, 0, sizeof(pad));
    print_unlock_patterns_r(pad, 0, 0, 0);
}

int main(void) {
    print_unlock_patterns();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123
894
765

123
874
965

123
654
789

129
438
567

145
236
987

189
276
345

187
296
345

167
258
349
```

Comment: It's a bit surprising that there are so few possible sequences!  It certainly means that 9-digit 'passcodes' following these rules are not secure.